# gentrification : equality or equity before the bounties

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Let's say that I was wise and posted / replied to questions for years and was rewarded by a very good reputation, of more than 30k points.

Now I can enjoy a premium *StackExchange* service by putting a 200 points bounty on all the questions I ask, whatever how they are interesting or have a character of emergency.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: It are your bounties, you can spend them how you like. You don't need to offer them on your own questions, you know?

Comment: What I say is that if you got a lot of reputation you can have more responses, quicker, and more precise by putting a bounty on each question you are asking because it costs you nothing. And then gain a superior service all the rest of your "life".

Comment: @Marc Worth pointing out that people with such high reps are usually experienced enough that they don’t tend to ask questions: their participation tends to be focused on posting answers. For example, I have 25k on EL&U; I have a hard time coming up with questions to ask where it would be easier or faster to outsource it to my peers there than it would be to simply research it myself. In short, SO has been around for a decade, and the problem you worry about here hasn’t manifested yet.

Comment: "*because it costs you nothing*" A bounty of 200 points costs you 200 points, which is not the same as 0 points.

Comment: Adding a bounty doesn't guarantee you'll get any answers at all, let alone a "quicker and more precise" answer. I've seen plenty of questions whose bounties expired without any new answers being posted.

Comment: You can start a bounty at 500, and a good question might earn back some or more than all of that reputation, but you're loosing 100% of the bountied amount and risking rewarding half of it for an answer that you don't want to pay for.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche 200 points costs you relatively less when you have 30k points than when you have 350 points. It's like money.

Comment: @F1Krazy "Adding a bounty doesn't guarantee you'll get any answers at all" : it helps for that, however.

Comment: @Marc - I ignore questions with a bounty.  I will specifically wait until after the bounty expires to post an answer to the question

Comment: there are 190,321 bounties started by OPs with an average rep of 11,521. Of those questons 181,738 got at least one answer, where 124,250 got an accepted answer. Only 32,721 bounties were started on other users questions. It is awful. Here is the raw-data: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1291863

Answer (score 18):

No, you're right; those users have *earned* that premium service by putting in a lot of effort to reach that reputation level. Also, most of those users tend to post many answers but only very few questions; the least we can do for them as a community is have an extra look in the rare occasion when they *do* have a question.

About the emergency you mentioned: note that bounties can only be posted when the question is at least 48 hours old; most (decent) questions receive an answer before that period. So you can't really rely on it when you're in a rush. Nothing beats posting well-researched and well-written questions.

Comment: It's not a matter of being on the rush. It's a matter of that now 100% of your questions will be able to receive special attention. Even those with little interest, Because you can "pay". Sometimes I see rewarded questions that shouldn't really been bountied. A look aside shows me often a 10k+ member. It's not abnormal, if he can pay. But it causes a kind of problem of equality or equity.

Comment: Well @Marc I wonder what kind of questions you think don't deserve a bounty. If they are really poor or off-topic questions the community has 48 hours to close the question, before it becomes eligible for a bounty. Otherwise a question is a question.

Comment: @Luuklag - I have seen users use a bounty to prevent a question from being closed.  This has happen more than a handful of times.  It happens so many times, there is talk, about making so a bounty doesn't prevent the closure of a question.