# What drives you to keep accruing reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

So after 25k reputation points it seems that is the maximum of privileges here on meta or Stack Exchange. For users with 25k+, what is the drive to keep getting more reputation points?

I've seen some with like 140k reputation points and they aren't even moderators. They are just regular users like everyone else. Are there some hidden rewards for people that are 25k+ that isn't on the SE website that is inherited?

I haven't found any related question to this specific question.

**Update: 9-13-21 I’m getting some closed votes on this from this proposed question**

[gentrification : equality or equity before the bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353934/gentrification-equality-or-equity-before-the-bounties)

It’s a good answer but I don’t like the question. Negative 22 downvotes

The reason why I asked the question is to get a discussion going with high rep users and there say so on why they keep going when they reached the highest point

What is the end goal once you are at the top?

Comment: Your delete votes per day top out at 35K FWIW but then we [weep as there are no more worlds to conquer](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/526796-when-alexander-saw-the-breadth-of-his-domain-he-wept)

Comment: @RobertLongson Your daily flag limit tops out at 100k, so there's one last world to conquer until then :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes but you can get there much earlier by successful flagging if you want to. There are no such short cuts to delete vote numbers.

Comment: I get the impression that once you've written many questions and/ or answers that others find useful, the reputation you get from upvotes on those posts by new readers doesn't really stop. Not to say that anyone is intentionally lazy or anything, just that once you plant the right seeds so-to-speak, with quality content, you can sometimes reap the rewards for... basically ever. that said, I doubt somewhat that there are many users intentionally striving for rep once they've reached the 25k level and beyond.

Comment: At a certain point, motivations can shift away from "getting rep"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gentrification : equality or equity before the bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353934/gentrification-equality-or-equity-before-the-bounties)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users

Comment: I could imagine some HR folks would use a vanity metric like *"top 0.05% this year"* ***directly*** in hiring decisions (or the absolute reputation points). Even if that is not actually the case, there is certainly the perception out there in some job seekers (like the perceived importance of algorithms due to the to-be-hired-at-[FAANG](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FANG#Noun) hype (fuelled by some of those companies' hiring practices)).

Comment: I'm here because I'm passionate about the site's topic, Stack Exchange. I don't really care about the rep; in my earlier years here, I didn't even have a registered account on which to earn rep for a long time.

Comment: You get swag for hitting 100k and 250k rep iirc

Comment: @zcoop98 "... reputation you get from upvotes ..." -  It's a popular belief that people simply are able to *live off their pension* after a certain number of years, it's [usually not the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StkaL.png), though [rarely it's possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHFz8.png), on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation&sort=graph).

Comment: I've voted to close this as primarily opinion based. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191774/369802) for an explanation of why questions on MSE *can* be closed as opinion based, boiling down to: The opinions you are asking for here don't matter for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tinkeringbell that was a great answer with lots of detail. Now that I have the close vote I can see why people want to close and there reasons

Answer (score 10):

Nothing.

What drives me to ask is wanting the answer. I like my questions being upvoted, but I mainly want the answer.

What drives me to answer is wanting to help and wanting to show off. Not getting rep as a way to unlock new privileges. Perhaps getting rep as a short form for "look how helpful I have been." And getting not-the-points-actual-reputation like "this person really knows what they're talking about."

I don't care what my numbers are. I am over 100k on one site, and over 40k on 3, but I had to check the dropdown to know that. Rep isn't really what motivates most people. Getting an upvote (or dozens of them) motivates lots of us - the total rep is just an accumulated reminder of those dopamine hits.